# Samson Meteor Mic under Linux/ALSA

Tags: linux, audio, usb, alsa

Has anybody gotten a Samson Meteor Mic working under Linux/ALSA?

I tried to google it but I found no mention of Samson Meteor under Linux at all.

Kernel/ALSA/Audacity see the device. Unfortunately I was unable to record anything. `arecord` refuses to work and Audacity freezes completely when I press the record button.

`arecord -l` gives me:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
...
card 1: Mic [Samson Meteor Mic], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`arecord -L` gives me:

```
...
default:CARD=Mic
    Samson Meteor Mic, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Mic,DEV=0
    Samson Meteor Mic, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Mic,DEV=0
    Samson Meteor Mic, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Mic,DEV=0
    Samson Meteor Mic, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Mic,DEV=0
    Samson Meteor Mic, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Mic,DEV=0
    Samson Meteor Mic, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Mic,DEV=0
    Samson Meteor Mic, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Mic,DEV=0
    Samson Meteor Mic, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
```

But, e.g. `arecord -f cd -D default:CARD=Mic` returns only error messages:

```
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:1052:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to start PCM stream
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:604:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
arecord: main:654: audio open error: Broken pipe
```

and in `dmesg` I find this:

```
...
[ 1750.460164] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: iso resched full ffff8801b3e02500 (now 128 max 8320)
[ 1750.460168] cannot submit datapipe for urb 0, error -28: not enough bandwidth
```

Additionally, full `dmesg` output when connecting the device:

```
[ 2030.857802] hub 2-1:1.0: state 7 ports 8 chg 0000 evt 0040
[ 2030.858084] hub 2-1:1.0: port 6, status 0101, change 0001, 12 Mb/s
[ 2030.961848] hub 2-1:1.0: debounce: port 6: total 100ms stable 100ms status 0x101
[ 2030.972865] hub 2-1:1.0: port 6 not reset yet, waiting 10ms
[ 2031.034704] usb 2-1.6: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 9
[ 2031.045748] hub 2-1:1.0: port 6 not reset yet, waiting 10ms
[ 2031.119403] usb 2-1.6: ep0 maxpacket = 16
[ 2031.120233] usb 2-1.6: skipped 10 descriptors after interface
[ 2031.120236] usb 2-1.6: skipped 2 descriptors after interface
[ 2031.120238] usb 2-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after endpoint
[ 2031.120240] usb 2-1.6: skipped 2 descriptors after interface
[ 2031.120242] usb 2-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after endpoint
[ 2031.120243] usb 2-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after interface
[ 2031.120443] usb 2-1.6: default language 0x0409
[ 2031.122480] usb 2-1.6: udev 9, busnum 2, minor = 136
[ 2031.122482] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=17a0, idProduct=0310
[ 2031.122485] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2031.122486] usb 2-1.6: Product: Samson Meteor Mic
[ 2031.122488] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: Samson Technologies
[ 2031.122563] usb 2-1.6: usb_probe_device
[ 2031.122566] usb 2-1.6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[ 2031.122693] usb 2-1.6: adding 2-1.6:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
[ 2031.122735] snd-usb-audio 2-1.6:1.0: usb_probe_interface
[ 2031.122739] snd-usb-audio 2-1.6:1.0: usb_probe_interface - got id
[ 2031.139846] usb 2-1.6: adding 2-1.6:1.1 (config #1, interface 1)
[ 2031.139870] usb 2-1.6: adding 2-1.6:1.2 (config #1, interface 2)
[ 2031.139890] usb 2-1.6: adding 2-1.6:1.3 (config #1, interface 3)
[ 2031.139916] usbhid 2-1.6:1.3: usb_probe_interface
[ 2031.139917] usbhid 2-1.6:1.3: usb_probe_interface - got id
[ 2031.140837] input: Samson Technologies Samson Meteor Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.3/input/input12
[ 2031.140856] usb 2-1.6: link qh2-0601/ffff88016d9c4300 start 1 [1/2 us]
[ 2031.140890] usbhid 2-1.6:1.3: looking for a minor, starting at 96
[ 2031.140948] generic-usb 0003:17A0:0310.000A: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Device [Samson Technologies Samson Meteor Mic] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input3
[ 2031.140961] drivers/usb/core/inode.c: creating file '009'
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem and am very new to linux and rPI. How do I update my kernels? Also, after you updated, you simply typed "arecord -f cd -D default:CARD=Mic" and it worked? Thanks for any feedback,
Joe

Comment: Yes. When you figure it out, the mic starts to work and ugly messages disappear.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out that you have to enable `CONFIG_USB_EHCI_TT_NEWSCHED` in your kernel for this to start working. I tried to update the kernel but I had the same `not enough bandwidth` messages on my 4.1.15 until I enabled this flag.

Comment: Acutally you have to enable `CONFIG_USB_EHCI_TT_NEWSCHED` in your kernel for this to start working. I had the same `not enough bandwidth` messages on my 4.1.15 until I enabled this.

Comment: thanks @vasekch for the comment, that helped me to solve my issue.

Comment: probably it will better to update your answer :)